# Memory allocation using calloc

Tags: c

I want to initialize my large 2D array to zero.
if i allocate memory through calloc it will automatically initialize all the cells to zero.
Whether it is possible to allocate memory for 2D array using single  calloc function ?
Thank you

Comment: Yes it's possible, your question is very unclear. Why are you asking? Why did you try that didn't work?

Comment: Whether it can be done in one go, may depend on what you mean by a 2D array. Please given an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: How do i initialize my large 2d array to zero?  (Array size may be 10^12)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access the matrix elements by using the `[]` operator, you'll have to first allocate an intermediate structure that contains pointers to the data stored on each row of the matrix.

Each row will be zeroed because they're allocated using `calloc()`. Is this what you're looking for?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int **a;
    unsigned int num_rows = 2000;
    unsigned int num_columns = 190;

    a = calloc(num_rows, sizeof(*a));
    if (a == NULL) {
        /* TODO: Error handling. */
        return -1;
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
        a[i] = calloc(num_columns, sizeof(**a));
        if (a[i] == NULL) {
            /* TODO: Error handling. */
            return -1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);

    /* TODO: Free calloc'd memory. */    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
int nrows = 2000, ncolumns = 190;

int **a=calloc(nrows * ncolumns, sizeof(a));

printf("%d", a[0][0]);
```